# ansible playbook: print custom message if hosts variable is not defined

Tags: ansible

The simple playbook

```yaml
---
- name: NTP client
  # hosts: all:!ntpserver
  hosts: "{{ target_hosts }}"
  roles:
    - ntp_client
```

can be executed using

```bash
ansible-playbook -i hosts.yml -e target_hosts=<target host> <path to playbook> --ask-become-pass
```

This works just fine when `target_hosts` is set. In case `target_hosts` isn't set it obviously fails with

```
ERROR! The field 'hosts' has an invalid value, which includes an undefined variable. The error was: 'target_hosts' is undefined
```

How do I print a custom message such as

```
The variable 'target_hosts' is not set, use e.g. '-e target_hosts=all:!ntpserver'.
```

Note, I am aware that a default can be set via a `hosts` line like

```yaml
hosts: "{{ target_hosts | default('all:!ntpserver') }}"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a localhost play for validating input arguments as given below. This will fail with a custom message if the 'target_hosts' var is not defined.

```yaml
---

- name: Validate target_host variable
  hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - fail:
        msg: The variable 'target_hosts' is not set, use e.g. '-e target_hosts=all:!ntpserver'.
      when: target_hosts is not defined


- name: NTP client
  # hosts: all:!ntpserver
  hosts: "{{ target_hosts }}"
  roles:
    - ntp_client
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the filter *mandatory*. For example,

```yaml
- hosts: "{{ target_hosts|mandatory('The variable target_hosts is mandatory') }}"
```

---

Example of a complete playbook

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: "{{ target_hosts|mandatory(err001) }}"
  vars:
    err001: >-
      The variable 'target_hosts' is not set,
      use e.g. '-e target_hosts=all:!ntpserver'
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: hello
```

gives

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml 
ERROR! The variable 'target_hosts' is not set, use e.g. '-e target_hosts=all:!ntpserver'
```